# Slater determinant of three fermions without spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, fermions, identical-particles

The Slater determinant takes into account the Pauli principle, but if the fermions have no spin, a degree of freedom is missing. What would the determinant look like then?

Comment: what is the meaning of spinless fermions?

Comment: @schris38 See for example [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15596/how-can-we-have-spinless-fermions) and the comments [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/615237/hilbert-space-of-a-spinless-fermion).

Comment: Wavefunctions have a spin part and spatial part. If they are effectively spinless, Slater just serves to anti-symmetrize the spatial part.

Answer (score 3):

A Slater determinant
\begin{align}
\left\vert \begin{array}{ccc}
\psi_1(x_a)&\psi_1(x_b)&\psi_1(x_c)\\
\psi_2(x_a)&\psi_2(x_b)&\psi_2(x_c)\\
\psi_3(x_a)&\psi_3(x_b)&\psi_3(x_c)\end{array}
\right\vert
\end{align}
will be antisymmetric in the spatial part and so can be combined with a symmetric spin states, such as $\vert +\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\vert +\rangle_3$, to yield a fully antisymmetric wavefunction.